# Custom Fields Widgets with Dynamic Forms

Tags: forms

In Customs Field, We always use element as a Form element

but some code isn't the same. i am a little confused!

the code below can work at Form but not at the Field Widget

```
function mycustomfield_field_widget_form(&$form,&$form_state,$field,$instance,$langcode,$items,$delta,$element)
{
    $base=$element;

    $element['toggle_me']=array(
         '#type' => 'checkbox',
         '#title' => t('Tick this box to type'),

    )+$base;

    $element['settings']=array(
         '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#states' => array(
         // Only show this field when the 'toggle_me' checkbox is enabled.
          'visible' => array(
         ':input[name="toggle_me"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),)+$base;
return $element;
}
```

i don't know why the settings textfield showed even if the checkbox doesn't check?

Thx for reading My Question!

I appreciate that!

Comment: Have you confirmed in the markup that the toggle_me element's name attribute is definitely "toggle_me" after the widget form's been processed?

Comment: Thx a lot , i just add the '#name' attributes,and the problem fixed. Thank you very much! You help me fix my problem many times!